# I need the program to stop asking if user name and password are Ok

Tags: c#, passwords

I have created this user ID and password console application. First, I ask and verify that they enter an ID integer and not a string. Next, I ask for a password; if the user ID and password match Predetermined values I added to the application to verify for, it log the user in. Apparently works good, but If user and password are ok at first time, instead of stop, it continues asking for ID name and password, I have tried break, and it doesn't work. Thanks.

```cs
using System;

namespace UserId
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text;
            var username = 123;
            string password = "valid";

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please,Enter your user ID number :");
                text = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(text, out username))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please, Enter a valid ID number such as a 12345");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password:");
                    password = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                if (username == 123 && password != "valid")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect user ID and password combination, Try again");
                }
            }

            if (username == 123 && password == "valid")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are now logged in!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: *I have tried break, and it doesn't work* - can you show us?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if ((username == 123 && password != "valid") || (username != 123 && password == "valid"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect user ID and password combination, Try again");
}
else
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tontonsevilla. It worked! I was using break in a different way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your code to this. It will check if either of username or password is incorrect it will prompt error otherwise it will logged in and not ask for the second time

```
if (username != 123 || password != "valid")
{
   Console.WriteLine("Incorrect user ID and password combination, Try again");
}

else
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Muhammad. It worked! I was using break in a different way, thanks.

Comment: @diasalva accept my answer and vore it out if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Create a C++ program that allows the user to input their personal details including first name, last name, course, username, and password. The program should then verify the entered username and password. If the password is verified, the program will concatenate the first name and password together. In case the password is incorrect, an error message will be displayed.